# Can the exact same mysql query return diffrent results

Tags: python, mysql

**Problem description**

I have the following python code running on one server accessing a mySQL database on another server. I can succesfully query the database and get correct results in all other cases so far, but one query has been returning strange results, so, turning to debugging I wrote the following code:

```
    with closing(self.db.cursor()) as c:
        c.execute(myQuery, myParams)       
        self.logger.log("QUERY: %s" % (c._executed,))
```

with myQuery holding a valid mySQL query, and myParams being a list of 3 integers. The 'logger' simply writes what I put into it to a file. In other words, this code will capture exactly the query sent to the mysql server. Copying the query into either the mySQL command line on said server or running it via the phpmyadmin running on that server gets me 1 result. However, running (the first statement in the same 'with' block):

```
        results = c.fetchall()  
    self.logger.log("%s results" % (len(results),))
```

Gives me a '0 results' message.

One more interesting tidbit: I iterate over the results using this pattern:

```
for row in results: 
        x = Foo(row[2])
        y = Bar(row[0], row[1], x)
```

I verified that this pattern actually works for another query with is a 'smaller' version of the query that causes a problem, e.g. here there's actually a non-zero amount of results with valid data in the database via python. That query is quite similar, but not exactly the same. See the Query details section for both queries.

**The question:**

How is that even possible?

---

**Versions**

SQL reports version; 5.5.37-0+wheezy1

Python reports version: 2.7.9. using GCC 4.9.2. linux2

---

**Other information**

Used python modules:

```
import mysql.connector, sys, os
```

---

**Query details**:

I can't provide the exact query, but can provide a version with variable names replaced by a, b, c, etc.

This query returns no results, when it should return some (e.g. it returns results on the console)

```
SELECT A.a1, B.b1, B.ID 
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A ON A.a2 = B.ID 
INNER JOIN C ON B.ip & C.m = C.ip & C.m AND C.m < B.m
INNER JOIN D ON C.ID = D.d1
WHERE B.b2 = %s AND D.d2 = %s AND D.d3 = %s
```

This query actually **does** return results, via python as well as on the console. Note how this is almost exactly the same query, there's one 'join' stripped out and replaced by its result:

```
SELECT A.a1, B.b1, B.ID
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.a2 = B.ID 
INNER JOIN C ON B.ip & C.m = C.ip & C.m AND C.m < B.m
WHERE C.ID = %s AND B.b2 = %s
```

Where the types are the following:

```
<X>.ID: INT UNSIGNED for all <X> (primary key, indexed)
<X>.ip: INT UNSIGNED for all <X>
<X>.m: INT UNSIGNED for all <X>
A.a1: TINYTEXT
B.b1: SMALLINT UNSIGNED    
A.a2: INT UNSIGNED (fkey to B.ID, indexed)
D.d1: INT UNSIGNED (fkey to C.ID, indexed)
B.b2: SMALLINT UNSIGNED (fkey to F.ID, indexed)
D.d2: SMALLINT UNSIGNED (fkey to F.ID, indexed)
D.d3: INT UNSIGNED (fkey to E.ID, indexed)
```

Comment: I see two possibilities: either the query run in python is not actually the same as run in mysql console, or the data is changing while you query (is db used in live application?)

Comment: What python module do you use for the database connection?

Comment: Note you should use [`c.rowcount`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-rowcount.html). Once you called `cursor.fetchall()` you "empty" the cursor buffer.

Comment: Using `len(results)` should not depend on the cursor buffer though, as results is just a regular list.